# Vertica UDx RPC Timeout

Tags: r, timeout, user-defined-functions, vertica

We're encountering an error when trying to create a UDF function after updating several R libraries within Vertica.

ROLLBACK 3399: Failure in UDx RPC call InvokeGetUdxType(): timed out in receiving a UDx message

We were testing UDF management and creation when this happened. Last week we were able to successfully create basic libraries and functions. However since the update we encountered this error when deleting and recreating UDF's that were already working.

Has anyone encountered an error like this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that an R library was broken during an update but it was difficult to determine which one. The solution used was to reinstall the vertica+R rpm.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have tryed to load the UDx as C++ libs.
To fix try to issue the "CREATE LIBRARY " specifing the R libs.
 Give it  try let me know what happened !

Comment: The CREATE LIBRARY statemente included the specification for the R language. We reinstalled vertica+R rpm and this rolled us back to the previous working state.

The only explanation we came up with was that something in vertica's R interpreter was broken after updating libraries. We couldn't find it outside of a UDF creation so we chose to reinstall.

Hope this works for someone in the future. 

[XKCD](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png)